# angular-meteor : weird behaviour in directive namespace between routes.js and components

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I don't understand why have we this kind of behaviour ?

Is it an obligation to use a "lowercase" directive ?

**This is work :**

```
// client/routes.js
angular.module('socially').config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider     
    .state('subjects', {
      url: '/subjects',
      template: "<subjectslist></subjectslist>"
    })
    ...

// client/subjects/subjects-list/subjects-list.html
angular.module('socially').directive("subjectslist", function() {
  return {
    ...
```

**This is work :**

```
// client/routes.js
angular.module('socially').config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider     
    .state('subjects', {
      url: '/subjects',
      template: "<blablabla></blablabla>"
    })
    ...

// client/subjects/subjects-list/subjects-list.html
angular.module('socially').directive("blablabla", function() {
  return {
    ...
```

**1) Why this is not working ?**

```
// client/routes.js
angular.module('socially').config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider     
    .state('subjects', {
      url: '/subjects',
      template: "<subjects-list></subjects-list>"
    })
    ...

// client/subjects/subjects-list/subjects-list.html
angular.module('socially').directive("subjects-list", function() {
  return {
    ...
```

**2) Why this is not working ?**

```
// client/routes.js
angular.module('socially').config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider     
    .state('subjects', {
      url: '/subjects',
      template: "<subjectsList></subjectsList>"
    })
    ...

// client/subjects/subjects-list/subjects-list.html
angular.module('socially').directive("subjectsList", function() {
  return {
    ...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the angular official site

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes. Convert
>   the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

And named is the angular-convention. If you dont want, you should try another JS framework.

**Update answer:**
In the last example, you need create correct component like follow code:

`template : <subjects-list><subjects-list>` instead of `subjectsList`

> `.state('subjects', {`
>         `url: '/subjects',`
>         `template: "<subjectsList></subjectsList>"`
>       `})`

Because when you declare in controller `subjectsList` directive, Angular will proccess directive's name and convert to `subjects-list` and find it in view.

Comment: thanks @kelvin, I try to understand but why this directive "subjects-list" doesn't work ?
Could you give me an example, please ?

Comment: With directive html-tag, you have to write lower-case (in html) and write camelCase (in controller). It is a basically convention of angular

Comment: ok weird but if it is a basically convention of angular, let's just follow the rule ;-) thank you